# Chessboard Java script advice need

Tags: javascript, foreach, structure, chess

I need to optymalise my chessboard code (JS) to avoid  soo many lines of copied code for the same chess piece like pawn, and other pieces.

I need to create better data structure i think , but i dont have good idea how to iterate my data structure to locate all pieces on the board.This  is [codepen link](https://codepen.io/Ragnarok1985/pen/qLovvr) for this project.

For example this is my function to place knight piece on the board.

```
   function addKnight() {
        //piece create function
        var KnightFirst = oneKnight[8];
        var KnightSecond = oneKnight[15];
        var KnightThird = oneKnight[48];
        var KnightFour = oneKnight[55];

        pieceKnight1 = document.createElement("i");
        pieceKnight1.classList.add("fas");
        pieceKnight1.classList.add("fa-chess-knight");
        pieceKnight2 = document.createElement("i");
        pieceKnight2.classList.add("fas");
        pieceKnight2.classList.add("fa-chess-knight");
        pieceKnight3 = document.createElement("i");
        pieceKnight3.classList.add("fas");
        pieceKnight3.classList.add("fa-chess-knight");
        pieceKnight4 = document.createElement("i");
        pieceKnight4.classList.add("fas");
        pieceKnight4.classList.add("fa-chess-knight");

        KnightFirst.appendChild(pieceKnight1);
        KnightSecond.appendChild(pieceKnight2);
        pieceKnight2.classList.add("color");
        KnightThird.appendChild(pieceKnight3);
        KnightFour.appendChild(pieceKnight4);
        pieceKnight4.classList.add("color");

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this. It isn't a complete code but just the structure.

```
var piece = {
    x, y,
    type,
    color,
    sprite: new Image(),

}
var pieces = [];

function addPieces () {

    if (i < 16) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
            pieces.push(piece);
            pieces[i].type = "pawn";

            if (j < 4) {
                //set position for white pawns
            } else {
                //set position for black pawns
            }
        } }

        if (i >= 16 && i < 20) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            pieces.push(piece);
            pieces[i].type = "knight";

            if (j < 2) {
                //set position for white knights
            } else {
                //set position for black knights
            }
        }}
        if (i >= 20 && i < 24) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            pieces.push(piece);
            pieces[i].type = "rook";

            if (j < 2) {
                //set position for white rooks
            } else {
                //set position for black rooks
            }
        }}

        if (i >= 24 && i < 28) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            pieces.push(piece);
            pieces[i].type = "bishop";

            if (j < 2) {
                //set position for white bishops
            } else {
                //set position for black bishops
            }
        }}

        if (i >= 28 && i < 30) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            pieces.push(piece);
            pieces[i].type = "queen";

            if (j < 1) {
                //set position for white queen
            } else {
                //set position for black queen
            }
        }}

        if (i >= 30 && i < 32) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            pieces.push(piece);
            pieces[i].type = "king";

            if (j < 1) {
                //set position for white king
            } else {
                //set position for black king
            }
        }    }            
    }
}
```

You could apply the same type of function for the update each frame, but that's your call. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thx for advice ill try to workout this .  In my code i create many variables for example pieceKnight1 ...2...3...4  is there are some way to create this variables (names) by the iteration ?     Mayby with use of template string  or something like that  ?  Like this pieceKnight$ and only one classList.add   instruction . To avoid this code multiplication ?>

Comment: The thing is you will have an array of "piece"s. For example, the first knight will be pieces[8]. You will access it with this identification

Comment: Just remember when you update, move the pieces in the right order (do not apply pawn movement to queen for example). I suggest if you do it this way you write down your array of objects so you reme

Comment: ...ber how you built it

Comment: Thx for your advice. This is helpfull.